# WPF Deployment Issue

Tags: wpf

I have created a WPF application and deployed it to a location on my PC. I have installed it fine but when I open the applicaiton link I keep getting an error message saying the `application has stopped working`. I am running this on the same PC that I created the application on.

Sorry if this is a silly and really easy fix but I am new to deploying applications so may have missed something out.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It`s usually a good idea to catch such unhandled exceptions and show some notification to user. To do so in WPF app you can add event handlers to `DispatcherUnhandledException` and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` in App class constructor.
This will allow you to show exception details in MessageBox or log them by any other means.

Comment: That has helped me find the error thank you. Will update my question with the findings

Answer (score 1):

That dialog invariably means there was an unhandled exception in your application and it isn't particular to WPF. There could be a lot of different issues that cause it.

If you start the application from the command line instead of double-clicking on it in the explorer, then Windows will dump the exception details to the command line after the program crashes. I would try that first and see if it's not something simple like you missed a DLL in your installer.

Comment: I know this may seem like a bad request but how would i run it from the command line?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response...you would just go to the installed directory, shift-right-click the folder and say "Open Command Window Here", and then type the name of the .exe file and hit enter. There's nothing that really makes a WPF windows application different from a console application in terms of how you run it, it's just that the WPF application spawns graphics - it will still spit errors out to the console.